# Importing csv file into R - numeric values read as characters

Tags: r

I am aware that there are similar questions on this site, however, none of them seem to answer my question sufficiently.

This is what I have done so far:

I have a csv file which I open in excel. I manipulate the columns algebraically to obtain a new column "A". I import the file into R using `read.csv()` and the entries in column A are stored as factors - I want them to be stored as numeric. I find this question on the topic:

[Imported a csv-dataset to R but the values becomes factors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187745/imported-a-csv-dataset-to-r-but-the-values-becomes-factors)

Following the advice, I include `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` as an argument in `read.csv()`, however, as Hong Ooi suggested in the page linked above, this doesn't cause the entries in column A to be stored as numeric values.

A possible solution is to use the advice given in the following page:

[How to convert a factor to an integer\numeric without a loss of information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-without-a-loss-of-information)

however, I would like a cleaner solution i.e. a way to import the file so that the entries of column entries are stored as numeric values.

Cheers for any help!

Comment: Excel is hosing with your text file.  Open the csv in a text editor to see what Excel is mangling.

Comment: Could it be a problem with decimal symbol? Check the decimal symbol used in CSV file. You can specify the character to be used as decimal symbol with `dec` option in `read.csv`. See `?read.csv` for more information.

Comment: do what Joshua tells you to do, excel as a tendency to destroy csv headers. normally i use options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE) to avoid the factors.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Whatever algebra you are doing in Excel to create the new column could probably be done more effectively in R.

Please try the following:   Read the *raw* file (before any excel manipulation) into R using `read.csv(... stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`.   [If that does not work, please take a look at `?read.table` (which `read.csv` wraps), however there may be some other underlying issue].

For example:

```
   delim = ","  # or is it "\t" ?
   dec = "."    # or is it "," ?
   myDataFrame <- read.csv("path/to/file.csv", header=TRUE, sep=delim, dec=dec, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Then, let's say your numeric columns is column 4

```
   myDataFrame[, 4]  <- as.numeric(myDataFrame[, 4])  # you can also refer to the column by "itsName"
```

---

Lastly, if you need any help with accomplishing in R the same tasks that you've done in Excel, there are plenty of folks here who would be happy to help you out

Comment: Thanks. This is a very helpful checklist. In this instance, the problem was resolved by doing the algebraic manipulation in R as opposed to Excel.

Answer (score 14):

In `read.table` (and its relatives) it is the `na.strings` argument which specifies which strings are to be interpreted as missing values `NA`. The default value is `na.strings = "NA"`

If missing values in an otherwise numeric variable column are coded as something else than "`NA`", e.g. "`.`" or "`N/A`", these rows will be interpreted as `character`, and then the whole column is converted to `character`.

Thus, if your missing values are some else than "`NA`", you need to specify them in `na.strings`.

Answer (score 9):

If you're dealing with large datasets (i.e. datasets with a high number of columns), the solution noted above can be manually cumbersome, and requires you to know which columns are numeric *a priori*.

Try this instead.

```
char_data <- read.csv(input_filename, stringsAsFactors = F)
num_data <- data.frame(data.matrix(char_data))
numeric_columns <- sapply(num_data,function(x){mean(as.numeric(is.na(x)))<0.5})
final_data <- data.frame(num_data[,numeric_columns], char_data[,!numeric_columns])
```

The code does the following:

1. Imports your data as character columns.
2. Creates an instance of your data as numeric columns.
3. Identifies which columns from your data are numeric (assuming columns with less than 50% NAs upon converting your data to numeric are indeed numeric).
4. Merging the numeric and character columns into a final dataset.

This essentially automates the import of your .csv file by preserving the data types of the original columns (as character and numeric).

Comment: Note that this method converts date/time columns to numeric columns as well!

Answer (score 3):

Including this in the `read.csv` command worked for me: `strip.white = TRUE`

(I found this solution [here](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/13589_1dc68b35cccc4686924ba80c37697b7e.html).)

Answer (score 1):

version for data.table based on code from dmanuge :

```
convNumValues<-function(ds){
  ds<-data.table(ds)
  dsnum<-data.table(data.matrix(ds))
  num_cols <- sapply(dsnum,function(x){mean(as.numeric(is.na(x)))<0.5})
  nds <- data.table(  dsnum[, .SD, .SDcols=attributes(num_cols)$names[which(num_cols)]]
                        ,ds[, .SD, .SDcols=attributes(num_cols)$names[which(!num_cols)]] )
return(nds)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  Based on Joshua's premise that excel was the problem I looked at it and found that the numbers were formatted with commas between every third digit.  Reformatting without commas fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, I had the similar situation here in my data file when I readin as a csv. All the numeric value were turned into char. But in my file there was a value with a word "Filtered" instead of NA. I converted "Filtered" to NA in vim editor of linux terminal with a command <%s/Filtered/NA/g> and saved this file and later used it and read it in R, all the values were num type and not char type any more.
Looks like character value "Filtered" was inducing all values to be char format.

Charu

Comment: Greetings! It would be super helpful if you could show your code explicitly rather than describing it in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Shawn Hemelstrand here are the steps in detail below:
[example matrix file.csv having 'Filtered' word in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qr7Bs.png)

I opened the file.csv in linux command terminal

> vi file.csv
> then press "Esc shift:"
> and type the following command at the bottom
> "%s/Filtered/NA/g"
> press enter
> then press "Esc shift:"
> write "wq" at the bottom (this save the file and quit vim editor)

then in R script I read the file

```
data<- read.csv("file.csv", sep = ',', header = TRUE)
str(data)
```

All columns were num type which were earlier char type.

In case you need more help, it would be easier to share your txt or csv file.