# calculate rmse in r using lapply

Tags: r, lapply

I have small csv files in a directory. I need to calculate rmse and mse from each file.

For example inside Barcelona.csv

```
City, RealMax, ForecastMax
Barcelona, 30, 29
Barcelona, 31, 29
Barcelona, 32, 31
Barcelona, 29, 29
Barcelona, 27, 29
```

I have the next code by now in R

```
setwd("/home/enric/csv")
filenames <- list.files(pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)  ###I open all the files csv
ldf <- lapply(filenames, read.csv, header=FALSE)
length(ldf)
ldf

foo <- function(x) {
# Function that returns Root Mean Squared Error
rmse <- function(error) {
sqrt(mean(error^2,na.rm = TRUE))
}

# Function that returns Mean Absolute Error
mae <- function(error) {
mean(abs(error))
}

error <- x$V2 - x$V3
mae <- mae(error)  
rmse <- rmse(error)   
return( list( mae = mae, rmse = rmse))
}

res <-lapply(ldf, foo)
```

and I get this message about factors...

```
> res <-lapply(ldf, foo)
Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(x$V2, x$V4) : - not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(x$V2, x$V4) : - not meaningful for factors
```

How can I convert factor to numerical in order to solve it? Well I think this is the problem, any help?

Comment: why use header = FALSE when you have a header? the entire csv file is being read in as strings which are converted to factors

Comment: now, yes! I have changed to TRUE

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have not read your data columns in as numeric. You can check the structure and classes of objects using `str()`. For converting while you're reading the file, look at the additional options of `read.csv()`, [especially `stringAsFactors`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706188/importing-csv-file-into-r-numeric-values-read-as-characters). You can change the class after the fact by coercing to numeric: `as.numeric()'.

Comment: and how can I save res[i] in different csv? for example, one file ErrorBarcelona.csv, and inside  the name of Barcelona and the values mae and rmse, and the same for the other cities?

Comment: At the end, I have solved it partially with this code, but I have to introduce still inside every file the name of the city         for (i in 1:6) { #I have 6 csv files
write.table(res[i], file=paste(i, ".csv", sep="") ,row.names=TRUE, col.names=TRUE, sep=",")
}