# Read.csv: some rows are missing

Tags: r, csv

I use:

```
read.csv('....csv', as.is=TRUE, header=TRUE)
```

There is a header in the first row and without that row there are still 72139 rows but I can only read 72138 rows. And I cannot figure out why R automatically omits a row.

I checked the first few rows and there is no problem with them.

Updated:
I tried another similar csv and R missed more than 10000 row......then i found my answer here...[read.csv in R doesn't import all rows from csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26094584/read-csv-in-r-doesnt-import-all-rows-from-csv-file)

I use quote="" in my read.csv() but then you have to be careful with your character variables.

I am still curious since some other csv files also have double quote but with fewer rows(approximately 30000) but I never had any mistake with them before...can anyone help me with this question?

thanks

Comment: which row is missing.. is it the last row?

Answer (score 1):

How do you count the rows in the file? `wc -l`? If there is one blank row (most possibly in the last of file), `wc` will include it also.

If not, you can write the dataframe out with `write.csv` and compare the result with original data file using something like `diff` to see which row is missing.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a dataset of 50,000 rows, with only about half importing using read.csv.None of the suggestions here and in other forums worked for me. What solved it immediately was a suggestion from my advisor to use read_csv instead, from the "readr" package. Here are instructions: https://readr.tidyverse.org/

Comment: An example would be a good thing to add in your answer.