# How do I add together the values of specific columns in R

Tags: r

My data set in R looks like this

```
      Id Gender   Age Participate    Q1   Q10    Q2    Q3    Q4
*  <int>  <chr> <int>       <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     16   Male    20           1     0     1     0     1     1
2     17   Male    40           1     1     0     0     0     0
3     18   Male    33           1     1     0     0     0     0
4     19   Male    18           1     1     0     0     0     0
5     20   Male    24           1     0     0     1     0     0
6     21 Female    42           1     0     0     1     0     0
7     22 Female    19           1     1     0     0     1     1
8     28 Female    49           1     0     1     1     0     0
9     29 Female    17           1     1     0     1     0     0
10    31   Male    18           1     1     0     1     0     0
```

I want to add together the numbers in Q1 - Q10 to create a score. How can I do this? 
Thanks

Comment: Just do `df1$Total <- rowSums(df1[6:10])` or with `dplyr` `df1 %>% mutate(Total = rowSums(.[grep("^Q\\d+", names(.))]))`  Based on the column types, you need to convert the `character` class to `numeric` with `as.numeric`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you saved your data into the R variable dat
To add Q1 with Q10 you could simply use:

```
score <- as.numeric(dat$Q1) + as.numeric(dat$Q10)
```

If you want to select more than two variables (e.g., Q1, Q2, Q3, Q10) you could do (similarly to Akrun suggestion):

```
score <- rowSums(dat[, paste('Q', c(1:3, 10), sep = '')])
```

Where `rowSums` is a function summing the values of the selected columns and `paste` creates the names of the columns to select (i.e., Q1, Q2, Q3, and Q10). As suggested by Akrun you should transform your columns with character data-type (or factor) to the numeric data type before calling `rowSums`. If the 'transformation' from numeric to character happens when you are importing the data please read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13706747/5065588) explaining that sometimes using `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` when importing data into R might resolve similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

reproduced your data :

```
      Id Gender   Age Participate    Q1   Q10    Q2    Q3    Q4
*  <int>  <chr> <int>       <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     16   Male    20           1     0     1     0     1     1
2     17   Male    40           1     1     0     0     0     0
3     18   Male    33           1     1     0     0     0     0
4     19   Male    18           1     1     0     0     0     0
5     20   Male    24           1     0     0     1     0     0
6     21 Female    42           1     0     0     1     0     0
7     22 Female    19           1     1     0     0     1     1
8     28 Female    49           1     0     1     1     0     0
9     29 Female    17           1     1     0     1     0     0
10    31   Male    18           1     1     0     1     0     0
```

first you need to convert Q1 and Q10 to numeric format since they're currently saved as character.

**Mutate_each** in the **Dplyr** package allows you to apply one or more functions to one or more columns to where **starts_with** in the same package allow you to select variables based on their names.

So using a combination of both you can do the following :

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(as.numeric), starts_with("Q"))
```

Look at the results :

```
str(data)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ Id         : int  16 17 18 19 20 21 22 28 23 31
 $ Gender     : Factor w/ 2 levels "Female","Male": 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2
 $ Age        : int  20 40 33 18 24 42 19 49 17 18
 $ Participate: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ Q1         : num  0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1
 $ Q10        : num  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
 $ Q2         : num  0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1
 $ Q3         : num  1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
 $ Q4         : num  1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

Your Q* variables are now numeric so you can treat them by selecting only the variables starting with "Q" using the **dplyr::select** verb and using **rowSumns** allows you to sum up all the columns of a given row so :

```
data %>% select(starts_with("Q")) %>% rowSums(.) -> data$Score
```

Where :

- `select(starts_with("Q"))` = Select the columns starting with Q
- `rowSums(.)` = sum up the selected columns
- `->` = assign the result to `data$Score`

and then you can check the results :

```
   Id Gender Age Participate Q1 Q10 Q2 Q3 Q4 Score
1  16   Male  20           1  0   1  0  1  1     3
2  17   Male  40           1  1   0  0  0  0     1
3  18   Male  33           1  1   0  0  0  0     1
4  19   Male  18           1  1   0  0  0  0     1
5  20   Male  24           1  0   0  1  0  0     1
6  21 Female  42           1  0   0  1  0  0     1
7  22 Female  19           1  1   0  0  1  1     3
8  28 Female  49           1  0   1  1  0  0     2
9  23 Female  17           1  1   0  1  0  0     2
10 31   Male  18           1  1   0  1  0  0     2
```