# Retaining numerical data from csv file

Tags: r, import-from-csv

I am trying to import a csv dataset which is about the number of benefit recipients per month and district. The table looks like this:

[image]

There are 43 variables (months) and 88 observations (districts).

Unfortunately, when I import the dataset with the following code:

```
D=read.csv2(file="D.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";", dec=".")
```

all my numbers get converted to characters.

I tried the `as.is=T` argument, and to use `read.delim`, as suggested by Sam in this post: [Imported a csv-dataset to R but the values becomes factors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187745/imported-a-csv-dataset-to-r-but-the-values-becomes-factors)
but it did not help.

I also tried deleting the first two columns in the original csv file to get rid of the district names (which is the only real non-numeric column) but I stil get characters in the imported data frame. Can you please help how I could retain my numerics?

Comment: Are thousands being imported with comma's? if so they will be read as characters. try grep(",", df$ColumnName) and see if grep gets any results.
Also it is helpful if you provide a "reproducible example" so that others can recreate your problem. Even submitting part of the data frame using dput(head(df)) would be useful.

Comment: Yes it is because of comma's. did you try dec="," ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Imported a csv-dataset to R but the values becomes factors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187745/imported-a-csv-dataset-to-r-but-the-values-becomes-factors)

Comment: Best may be to open csv file in Excel (or  Libreoffice spreadsheet) and remove ',' from number formatting (uncheck Thousands separator).

Comment: if you can't get it to read it as numeric you could convert them after importing using something like: `D[, -1] <- apply(D[, -1], 2, function(x) as.numeric(gsub(",", "", x)))`

Comment: Yes, thousands were imported with commas -- thank you for the hint. The dec="," argument did work in a sense that it retained numerics, however, it also added three zeros to the end of any number below 1000. The initial problem was that I transformed numeric values to characters when I copied columns from earlier xls sheets to a csv file by using the XLConnect package. I had to go back and specify colTypes in that code. After that numerics have been nicely retained and the commas disappeared too!