# select function error: no applicable method for select_' applied to an object of class "character"

Tags: r, select, read.csv

i just waned to select the column 6 to 53 in this data "dd2.survey.data.csv"

but select function doesn't work with that Error

> file.raw.items <- file.raw %>% select(7:53) %T>% print
>
> Error in UseMethod("select_") :    no applicable method for 'select_'
>   applied to an object of class "character"

```
getwd()
setwd("C:/Users/bargsang/Desktop")
dir()
dir("dd2.survey.data.csv")

library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr) # %T>% 
install.packages("psych")
install.packages("psy")
library(psych) # pca, fa
library(psy) # screeplot
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)

file.raw <- "dd2.survey.data.csv"
file.raw

file.raw.items <- file.raw %>% select(6:53) %T>% print
##At this moment, 
##select function doesn't work. how can i solve it?
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `read.csv()` or similar function to read your text file.

I'm not sure from your code whether you have other mistakes but where you currently have:

```
file.raw.items <- file.raw %>% select(6:53) %T>% print
```

You probably need to change it to something like:

```
file.raw.items <- read.csv(file = file.raw) %>% select(6:53) %T>% print()
```

In addition to missing read.csv() to read your file note you also ommitted the `()` at the end of `print()`.

Be aware this will first read the entire file into memory, then select columns 6:53, then save the data.frame to `file.raw.items`.

Please see `?read.csv` for options regarding specifying headers.

Also, note whether you want to use the additional option for `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to ensure text stays as text (unless of course you want text read as Factors).  [Imported a csv-dataset to R but the values becomes factors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5187745/10312356)

Comment: it was really basic thing.. Thank you very much.

Comment: due to this, I was not able to kickstart it. Thx

Comment: @bargsang Glad to help.  Don't forget please to mark the answer as selected if it answers your question and upvote if it warrants it: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)