# With Linear Regression: R treats Column as many Coefficients

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

R seems to be treating all of my values in a column as seperate coefficients instead of seeing them as numbers to analyze. When using a regression, it hence conducts a multiple linear regression instead of a single linear regression. How can I overcome this problem? :

[image: Summary of Regression]

Data set:

[image: Dataset]

To import the csv file, I've used the following code:

```
data <- read.csv("./path.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: your variable will be character or factor rather than numeric. Before modelling make sure of your data tyoes by inspecting your data with `str(data3)`

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5188502/8245406).

Comment: @user20650's comment is supported by the *left* alignment of the entries in your screenshot.